# correct usage of nested CV

Tags: regression, time-series, cross-validation

I am a beginner in Machine Learning and I want to compare prediction results of multiple regression models (such as Ridge, Lasso, ANN...) using **Nested Cross-Validation** on a time series dataset. I have searched and reviewed several online articles and come up with the following procedure (or algorithm I’d better say). The purpose of the procedure is to find best MSPE for all given regression models using nested CV.

Assume that our time series data is loaded into `dataSet`. I call `split` function to divide data set into two parts: main Training set (~70%) and Test set (~30%)

```
def split(self):
     trainRows = round(0.7 * self.dataSet.shape[0])
     self.mTrainSet = self.edaData.loc[0:trainRows - 1, :]
     self.mTestSet = self.edaData.loc[trainRows:, :]
     pass
```

then I call the following iterate function. I added a few comments to clarify each step.

```
#
def iterate(self) -> float:

     # defining outer (or parent) cross-validator (10 folds cv)
     tscv_ifold: TimeSeriesSplit = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits= 10) if (self.outerCV == None) else self.outerCV
     # defining inner (or child) cross-validator (5 folds cv)
     tscv_jfold: TimeSeriesSplit = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=  5) if (self.innerCV == None) else self.innerCV

     # independent variable name
     yName = 'Price (USD)'

     # {Date} field must be removed because of {StandardScaler} and 
     # regression calculation
     self.mTrainSet.drop(['Date'], axis= 1, inplace= True)
     self.mTestSet.drop(['Date'], axis= 1, inplace= True)

     # stores MSPE(s) as well as regression models' tuning parameters for outer iteration(s)
     outerResults: list[RegressionResult] = []
     # iterating over parent folds
     for i, (iTrainIndices, iTestIndices) in enumerate(tscv_ifold.split(self.mTrainSet)):
          iTrainSet = self.mTrainSet.loc[iTrainIndices]
          iTestSet = self.mTrainSet.loc[iTestIndices]

          # standardaization
          scaler = StandardScaler().fit(iTrainSet)
          iStandardTrainSet: pa.DataFrame = pa.DataFrame(scaler.transform(iTrainSet), columns= iTrainSet.columns) 
          iStandardTestSet: pa.DataFrame = pa.DataFrame(scaler.transform(iTestSet), columns= iTestSet.columns) 

          # stores MSPE(s) as well as regression models' tuning parameters for inner iteration(s)
          innerResults: list[RegressionResult] = []
          # defining inner (or child) cross-validator (5 folds cv)
          for j, (jTrainIndices, jTestIndices) in enumerate(tscv_jfold.split(iStandardTrainSet)):
               jTrainSet = iTrainSet.loc[jTrainIndices]
               jTestSet = iTrainSet.loc[jTestIndices]

               jyTrain: pa.Series = jTrainSet[yName]
               jxTrain: pa.DataFrame = jTrainSet.drop([yName], axis= 1)
               jyTest: pa.Series = jTestSet[yName]
               jxTest: pa.DataFrame = jTestSet.drop([yName], axis= 1)
               
               # running the inner regression and storing the result
               innerResults.append(self.regress(jxTrain, jyTrain, jxTest, jyTest, tscv_jfold))
          
          # finding the least MSPE for current j iteration
          jx = min(range(len(innerResults)), key= lambda i: innerResults[i].mspe)
          jBestTuningArgs = innerResults[jx].args

          iyTrain: pa.Series = iStandardTrainSet[yName]
          ixTrain: pa.DataFrame = iStandardTrainSet.drop([yName], axis= 1)
          iyTest: pa.Series = iStandardTestSet[yName]
          ixTest: pa.DataFrame = iStandardTestSet.drop([yName], axis= 1)

          # calculation A
          # running the outer regression and storing the result
          regResultA = self.regress(ixTrain, iyTrain, ixTest, iyTest, tscv_ifold)
          # calculation B
          # running the outer regression with calculated best-tuning-args and storing the result
          regResultB = self.regressEx(ixTrain, iyTrain, ixTest, iyTest, jBestTuningArgs)
          
          # storing the regression with the best MSPE for current i iteration
          outerResults.append(regResultA if (regResultA.mspe <= regResultB.mspe) else regResultB)

     # finding the least MSPE at the end of both inner and outer iteration
     ix = min(range(len(outerResults)), key= lambda i: outerResults[i].mspe)
     iBestTuningArgs = outerResults[ix].args

     yTrain: pa.Series = self.mTrainSet[yName]
     xTrain: pa.DataFrame = self.mTrainSet.drop([yName], axis= 1)
     yTest: pa.Series = self.mTestSet[yName]
     xTest: pa.DataFrame = self.mTestSet.drop([yName], axis= 1)
     
     regResult = self.regressEx(xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest, iBestTuningArgs)
     return regResult.mspe
```

`regress` and `regressEx` functions are as follow;

```
# regression calculation
def regress(self, 
     xTrain: pa.DataFrame, 
     yTrain: pa.Series, 
     xTest: pa.DataFrame, 
     yTest: pa.Series, 
     validator: TimeSeriesSplit
     ) -> RegressionResult:

     if (validator != None):
          # alpha = lambda ** (-1)
          cv = RidgeCV(alphas= np.arange(0.5, 2, 0.01), cv= validator, scoring= 'neg_mean_squared_error')
          # providing x train set as well as y train set (or series)
          cv.fit(xTrain, yTrain)

     # alpha is known here using cross-validation
     model: Ridge = Ridge() if (validator == None) else Ridge(alpha= cv.alpha_)
     model = model.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
     guess = model.predict(xTest)
     error = mean_squared_error(yTest, guess)
     
     _alpha = cv.alpha_ if (validator != None) else None
     return RegressionResult(mspe= error, alpha= _alpha)
```

and

```
# extended regression calculation
def regressEx(self,
     xTrain: pa.DataFrame, 
     yTrain: pa.Series, 
     xTest: pa.DataFrame, 
     yTest: pa.Series, 
     tuningArgs: dict
     ) -> RegressionResult:

     # alpha is known here using provided tuning parameters
     if ((tuningArgs != None) and (tuningArgs['alpha'] != None)):
          _alpha = tuningArgs['alpha']
     else:
          _alpha = None

     model: Ridge = Ridge() if (_alpha == None) else Ridge(alpha= _alpha)
     model = model.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
     guess = model.predict(xTest)
     error = mean_squared_error(yTest, guess)
     
     return RegressionResult(mspe= error, alpha= _alpha)
```

Would you please someone let me know if this procedure is correct?